# Active/Inactive Users

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check who are all active users (who all logged in last 7 days) and who all are inactive users (who has not logged in for last 7 days). I got 2 tables users and agencies. The table structure for users is as follows:

```
id  | first_name | email | agency_id | last_login
 __________________________________________________
 1     Sujith      suj@suj   19865      2018/03/01
 2     Naveen      nav@nav   15098      2018/02/09
 3     Salin       sal@sal   18452      2017/12/06
```

The table structure for agencies is as follows:

```
id  | first_name |    email |  name |       last_login
 _________________________________________________________________
19865     Sujith      suj@suj  Yatra Travels 2018/03/01
19865     Raghav      rag@rag  Yatra Travels 2018/02/09
15098     Naveen      nav@nav  Travels Ltd   2017/12/06
15098     Monika      mon@mon  Travels Ltd   2017/12/06
18452     Raghu       rag@rag  MK Travels
```

The explanation is Users table contains the main agency details and agencies table contains the staffs working for the agencies. so the query has to check which agencies has logged in for 7 days(Active Users) and which agencies has not logged in for 7 days (Inactive users). I have written a query for Active Users. I need to recheck if its a correct query. and how will i write a query for Inactive users who has not logged in for 7 days or last_login IS NULL

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.email, users.last_name, users.last_login, agencies.name, 
agencies.id as agencyid FROM users  INNER JOIN agencies ON users.agency_id=agencies.id 
where users.last_login between adddate(now(),-7) and now() group by agencies.name 
order by agencies.name
```

Pls anyone can help me out? Thanx in advance.

Comment: how to differentiate inactive users from the above tables?

Comment: There are some criterias. is should take from both the tables from agencies_id. The field to validate is last_login. I have to display users who has not logged in for 7 days and 30 days.

Comment: check my below query
for 30 days between SUBDATE(now(),interval 30 DAY);  and now()

Comment: Any answer that recommends GROUP BY as part of the solution is, I'm afraid, as deluded as the questioner. For actual useful help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```html
where users.last_login >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY group by agencies.name 
order by agencies.name
```

Comment: Thank you. And what will be the query for inactive users that is users who has not logged in for 30 days

Comment: users.last_login <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY

Comment: where users.last_login <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY group by agencies.name 
order by agencies.name

Answer (score -1):

try the below query for active users

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.email, users.last_name, users.last_login, agencies.name, agencies.id as agencyid FROM users  INNER JOIN agencies ON users.agency_id=agencies.id where users.last_login between SUBDATE(now(),interval 7 DAY)  and now() group by agencies.name order by agencies.name
```

and Inactive users

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.email, users.last_name, users.last_login, agencies.name, agencies.id as agencyid FROM users  INNER JOIN agencies ON users.agency_id=agencies.id where (users.last_login < SUBDATE(now(),interval 7 DAY) or users.last_login is null) group by agencies.name order by agencies.name
```

Comment: Its working perfect and what will be the query for inactive users?

Comment: how to differentiate inactive users, please give some sample data

Comment: active users are those who have logged in last 7 days. Inactive users are those who have not logged in for last 7 days and last_login field is NULL is also inactive users.

Comment: SELECT users.first_name, users.email, users.last_name, users.last_login, agencies.name, agencies.id as agencyid FROM users  INNER JOIN agencies ON users.agency_id=agencies.id where (users.last_login < SUBDATE(now(),interval 7 DAY) or users.last_login is null) group by agencies.name order by agencies.name